# Access json value of current object

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code

```
var obj = {
    "vala" : function(arg){...}
    "valb" : obj.vala    // because the function to assign here is same in code.
}
```

I cannot create function outside of `obj` object.
I tried `"valb" : this.vala` but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any JSON here.

Comment: JavaScript objects are not JSON. You can't read a property of a JavaScript object from a variable before you've created the object and assigned it to that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference an object during initialization when using object literal syntax. You need to reference the object after it is created.

or you can create a constructor function

```
var settings = new function() {
    this.user = "someuser";
    this.password = "password";
    this.country = "Country";
    this.birthplace = this.country;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access vala during initialisation like that. But you can add valb after obj is created:

```js
var obj = {
  "vala" : function(arg){ console.log(arg); }       
}

obj["valb"] = obj.vala;

console.log(obj.vala(1));
console.log(obj.valb(2));
```

Comment: already marked as duplicate, no need to answer ..